# MS Access SQL Query does not include specified expression as aggregated function

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT CarBrand.BrandName, Count(Cars.ColorName) AS CountOfGreenProducts
FROM (Cars 
INNER JOIN CarFacts ON Cars.CarKey = CarFacts.CarKey) 
INNER JOIN CarBrand ON CarFacts.BrandKey = CarBrand.BrandKey
GROUP BY CarBrand.BrandName
HAVING Cars.ColorName = "Green";
```

I'm trying to grab a count of all green cars, but I receive an error that states "Your query does not include the specified expression Cars.ColorName = "Green" as part of an aggregate function" I would appreciate any help on how to fix this error. Thanks!

Comment: Try moving that to your `WHERE` criteria instead of the `HAVING` criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on sgeddes comment above.

You'll want to move the criteria from your `HAVING` Clause to the `WHERE` clause. The reason for this is that `WHERE` clauses are executed before aggregation. In other words, the database will filter out any records from your `Cars` table and the resulting `INNER JOIN` before it does the `COUNT(Cars.ColorName)`.

`HAVING`, on the other hand, filters AFTER aggregation. It's pretty much the last step the Database will take against the recordset. So when you say `HAVING Cars.ColorName = "Green"` the database gets confused because `Cars.ColorName` is not a field in your result set. `CountOfGreenProducts` does exist in the result set but you can't filter it for "Green" since it's a number. So the DB throws an error.

So, Instead:

```
SELECT CarBrand.BrandName, Count(Cars.ColorName) AS CountOfGreenProducts
FROM (Cars 
    INNER JOIN CarFacts ON Cars.CarKey = CarFacts.CarKey) 
    INNER JOIN CarBrand ON CarFacts.BrandKey = CarBrand.BrandKey
WHERE Cars.ColorName = "Green"
GROUP BY CarBrand.BrandName;
```